# Postgres cant connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql

I'm running Debian server and use SSH to manage it. Today I tried to install Postgres and follow this steps to do it:

```
apt-get install postgresql

su - postgres

psql
```

After the last command I got:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I found several solutions in the Web, but all of them doesn't works for me. As example I found, that I need to delete "postmaster.pid" in here:

```
/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

But I have no such directory as "postgres" in my "var" folder...

Please, help...:(

Comment: After install, did you also initialize and start the database service?

Comment: No, I just use this three commands, that I wrote at the begin of that post. Can you tell me initialize command? And wich user I need to use for that command - root or postgres?

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct and normally sufficient except when something goes wrong with the automatic creation of the first cluster by `apt-get install postgresql`. Often there is an error message like this in the middle of the success reports:

> Error: could not create default cluster

Since you can't have done any work with postgres yet, purge the packages with

```
apt-get purge 'postgresql*'
```

then reinstall with

```
apt-get install postgresql
```

but this time, pay close attention to any error message that would imply that the initial cluster was not created, that will give the actual reason of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for that. After I found that Error - I saw, what prevents Postgres to create cluster. It was errors in my locale.